# Gulp build not generating any files

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-uglify, gulp-concat, gulp-minify-css

I am using the following gulp code to build my deployment files.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var minify = require('gulp-minify');
var cleanCss = require('gulp-clean-css');

gulp.task('pack-js', function () {  
    return gulp.src([
        'wp_theme/assets/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js', 
        'wp_theme/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js', 
        'wp_theme/assets/js/assets/js/device.min.js',
        'wp_theme/assets/js/app.js'
    ])
        .pipe(concat('app-min.js'))
        .pipe(minify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});

gulp.task('pack-css', function () { 
    return gulp.src([
        'wp_theme/assets/css/normalize.css', 
        'wp_theme/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css',
        'wp_theme/assets/js/slick/slick.css',
        'wp_theme/assets/js/slick/slick-theme.css',
        'wp_theme/assets/css/animate.min.css',
        'wp_theme/assets/fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css',
        'wp_theme/assets/fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css',
        'wp_theme/style.css',
    ])
        .pipe(concat('style.css'))
        .pipe(cleanCss())
   .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['pack-js', 'pack-css']);
```

Next, when I run the "gulp" command like I am not getting any error

```
$ gulp
[01:34:53] Using gulpfile ~/{directory path here}/gulpfile.js
[01:34:53] Starting 'pack-js'...
[01:34:53] Starting 'pack-css'...
[01:34:53] Finished 'pack-js' after 28 ms
[01:34:53] Finished 'pack-css' after 13 ms
[01:34:53] Starting 'default'...
[01:34:53] Finished 'default' after 39 μs
```

But in the "dist" folder which is in the same directory as of the "gulpfile.js" doesn't show any generated files.

I checked the version also.

```
$ gulp -v
[08:01:40] CLI version 3.9.1
[08:01:40] Local version 3.9.1
```

Anything I am doing wrong here?

Comment: What if you try just gulp.dest("dist"), should be enough.

Comment: I tried gulp.dest("dist") also but no luck. Any other idea?

Comment: Is the `wp_theme` folder in the same folder as `gulpfile.js` and the `dist` folder?

Comment: @lofihelsinki Yes, they are in the same folder. I've even tried inside the wp_theme folder but somehow the outcome is always same. Seems like somehow the src path isn't reaching the actual files.

Comment: Can you test if it works with this source: `gulp.src("./wp_theme/**/*.css")` ?

Comment: @lofihelsinki will give it a try and let you know. Thanks.